# left outer join where the tables are from two different database system

Tags: mysql, oracle, tableau-api

Is it possible to write a custom SQL query in tableau performing left outer join where one of the table is in the database which is a MySQL Database type and second table is in Oracle database kind. If its possible is there any specific syntax i should be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do a left out join in tableau for tables coming in from two different data sources.

In order to accomplish this you need to create two different data connections under the same data source. Follow below steps:

1. Create a connection to any required database.
2. Under connection on right side click on Add
3. Connect to the second database.
4. Drag and drop tables from both database to right side.
5. create the desired outer joins.