# LEFT JOIN operation when the tables are in two separate databases

Tags: mysql, tableau-api

I want to perform Left Outer Join on two tables where the tables are in two separate data bases ( i.e., one in Mysql database and One in Oracle database) 
Please let me know how to perform this Left join operation in the SELECT Query

Comment: That is impossible.

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53827169/left-outer-join-where-the-tables-are-from-two-different-database-system

Comment: You can refer to below link to get the details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53827169/left-outer-join-where-the-tables-are-from-two-different-database-system

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do a left out join in tableau for tables coming in from two different data sources.

In order to accomplish this you need to create two different data connections under the same data source. Follow below steps:

Create a connection to any required database.

Under connection on right side click on Add

Connect to the second database.

Drag and drop tables from both database to right side.

create the desired outer joins.

Comment: I want to write a custom SQL Query for the join operation in tableau

Comment: You can't write one SQL query to join data from two databases. (Which one would execute the query?) Tableau does however have 2 features that allow you to combine data from multiple databases - You can do a cross database join in Tableau (which is implemented by a federated set of queries) or you can *blend* data from multiple data sources (which is implemented by separate aggregate queries). In both cases, the resulting data is combined in Tableau after it is provided by the underlying data sources.

Comment: " or you can blend data from multiple data sources (which is implemented by separate aggregate queries) " please explain this